# Prism/mvvm: how to bind GotFocus of View to an action?

Tags: mvvm, focus, prism

I've got a prism/mvvm view and want to notify the ViewModel if the View has got or lost the focus.

I'd guess I'd need to bind GotFocus of the View to an action in the ViewModel, but I got no idea how to get started on this.

Sure this is a standard problem which has been solved somewhere, and it's just me not finding the solution?

Comment: Do you want to execute an action on the viewmodel when the View raises the event GotFocus/LostFocus?

Comment: @Jehof, yes. I wonder if there is a MVVM way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [InvokeCommandAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity.invokecommandaction%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) behavior. This behavior is defined in the assembly System.Windows.Interactivity which is part of Expression Blend. With this behavior you could bind to the GotFocus event of your view and execute a command in your viewModel.

The same approach can you use for LostFocus. [Here](http://blogs.u2u.be/peter/post/2010/10/19/Invoking-commands-from-events-using-the-InvokeCommandAction-behavior.aspx)´s an example how to use InvokeCommandAction.

One thing about GotFocus of UserControl. You should know that the GotFocus event of the View is raised when a control, such as TextBox, gets the focus. You can´t focus the UserControl by its self.

**[Update]**
GotFocus of the UserControl is raised when IsTabStop is set to true

<s>Can´t you use the [IActiveAware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.iactiveaware%28v=PandP.38%29.aspx) interface of the prism framework. The IsActive property gets set when the view gets navigated in the region.</s>

The interface can be implemented on the View and the ViewModel (requires that the viewmodel instance is set as DataContext of the view) to be notified when the view is activated in the region.

Comment: IActiveAware doesn't do anything for Focus. IActiveAware is meant to signal if a view is active in, say, a tab control, or the view is the one currently shown in a region with a singular view, like a ContentControl

Comment: @Anderson Imes: Of course you are right, i thought he meant when a view gets active cause he is using prism. If he meant the events Got/Lost Focus, then IActiveAware cann´t do anything.